# How can I match some view if I have variable which has content associated with that view?

Tags: android, kotlin

For example, I have variable with content "EUR" or other content like "USD". How can I do something like this:

```
if (someVariable == anyCurrency) { // in this case anyCurrency should be "EUR". If anyCurrency would be USD, body should be USDTextView.text = "changeText"
EURTextView.text = "changeText"
}
```

instead of:

```
if (someVariable == "EUR") {
  EURTextView.text = "changeText"
}

else if (someVariable == "USD") {
  USDTextView.text = "changeText"
}
```

and etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: need more information on this

Comment: What else should I provide?

Comment: adding more info on what is your UI and what are you trying to achieve. How much complex it is.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What do you want the user to see? And what actions should they be able to take? You are digging too deep into the details of how to implement something without clearly specifying what the result should be.

Comment: There are many TextViews in HorizontalScrollView (169). If I have random value (for example `"EUR"`), I want to change text of TextView named exactly EURTextView. If I create 169 if statements, they can affect latency.

Comment: I think you should be using recyclerview instead of horizontal scroll view, and then handle your conditions. because 169 text views in scroll view is huge.

Comment: @HappySingh Thanks. Have never used it. Need to try.

Comment: @GrandPC it's very difficult to understand what you're asking for. But if you want the textview to change dynamically based on `someVariable`, you should look into https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata. If you want to show a list of textviews all at once, you should use RecyclerView.